# Converting Ubuntu Legacy with Windows installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I made a Bootable USB with Rufus, but my Ubuntu boot is on UEFI while my Windows is on Legacy. How do I convert my Ubuntu to Legacy? I don't have Separate/boot/efi partition, as seen on boot repair. I'm currently running a live USB

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to enable legacy boot?

Comment: To be able to do a dual-boot?

Comment: You can dual boot with uefi boot , you can only have one bootloader on mbr , which in case would have to be grub , so if you want  to  dual boot with legacy you will need to  override the bootloader with a grub install

Comment: Yeah, my Windows boot is Legacy sadly

Comment: Boot the Rufus made installer USB in Legacy, (BIOS), mode if you want to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode. After install run `sudo update-grub` to put windows on Ubuntu's boot loader.

Comment: Is that an option I can change on BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options

1. Convert Windows to UEFI boot (GPT) in command  prompt (search cmd in taskbar -> right click run as admin -> type in using `mbr2gpt.exe /convert /allowfullOS` in Windows ,  make sure you switch your bios settings to  uefi boot! , othewise it wont boot (may need to select windows efi boot on efi partition  driveletterwitharound100mbspace:/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi)
2. Reinstall grub(on linux) on mbr  (legacy) to enable dual boot windows + linux , note  you will loose windows boot loader .

**Highly recommend having a live linux live usb + windows usb installer (make one now) just incase it goes pear shaped.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not gonna make one sadly, I would rather delete all data on my disk. Another question: will my system mark Windows no longer existed if I choose "erase disk and install Ubuntu"?

Comment: That will delete al your data including windows and just install Ubuntu from fresh , which im guessing you want  to avoid ,

Comment: First option is  better ,  but if you really want legacy boot(grub boot override windows bootloader , follow this guide http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm#:~:text=1%20How%20to%20Reinstall%20Grub%20Onto%20Your%20MBR,The%20procedures%20in%20section%201.1%20were%20meant%20

Comment: Yeah. I changed my mind, I don't fully understand about OS stuff. At first I would like to install 2 OS's, now I need only one OS. My dad could help me with this but nah. It's fine for me- although I might try it. Thanks for your Help!

Comment: If you want to delete windows you can just use gparted ,  note you should backup your data on windows (if you have  emails , documents ,etc).

Comment: Install program using this  command on terminal  `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install gparted ntfs-3g` , it will allow you to delete windows from linux , and read/write to  ntfs on windows partition as well

Comment: I don't have many stuff there, but I do have 12 GB of data backup on my other USB. So I can delete windows partition on Ubuntu safely?

Comment: Yes , make sure that you select the correct drive to delete from (indicated by size and mount point and partition labels) in gparted/gnome disk, if this is a shared pc, ask anyone if they need their data/passwords? before you start , post a  screenshot/upload to  imgur if you arent sure

Comment: Okay, might try that. Thanks for your help

Comment: np  , happy  to  help :)